# ImportError: No module named pathlib

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following when I run pip list - I am on 2.7 over mac os:

```
➜ python --version   
Python 2.7.10



➜ pip list        
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Package            Version
------------------ -------
pathlib            1.0.1  
pip                19.0.2 
python-http-client 3.2.7  
setuptools         40.8.0 
wheel              0.33.0
```

Now in my code I have:

```
from pathlib import Path
```

and when I run from command line I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testexe.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

Comment: normally, this means that the python binary you are using isn't the same as the one that has access to pathlib.  where is your python binary?

Comment: I am running everything from the same place in terminal

Answer (score 4):

You can install a backwards compatible version of the current pathlib library from PyPI here: [pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/)

The original pathlib library is not maintained anymore. I'm not sure why it would but perhaps that's affecting your import ¯_(ツ)_/¯

**You should use Python 3 unless you absolutely have to use Python 2.** The pathlib module has been included as part of the standard library since Python 3.4. So while it might be annoying to swap, at least your pathlib import will work!

Comment: Actually I am using this in a makefile rule, to execute a py file. This will be distributed over git and run on multiple *NIX env's now as osx still supplies 2.7 as default python I wanted to do it that way.

Comment: Oh cool. You could try: `sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall pathlib` ... but other than that I'm no help sorry. Good luck!